# Python datetime - return %f as zeroes if there is not %f in original timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to subtract one timestamp to another.

Here's how I do it:

```python
t1 = data[3]
t2 = data[4]
d1 = datetime.strptime(str(t1), "%H:%M:%S.%f")
d2 = datetime.strptime(str(t2), "%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(d2-d1)
```

It works fine only if the format of `t1` and `t2` is always `%H:%M:%S.%f`, but in my case, `data[3]` and `data[4]` will return a random timestamp, wich will sometimes not always have `%f` in it. Because of this, python will raise the following error:

```plaintext
ValueError: time data '00:41:17' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Therefore, how can I make `t1` and `t2` always have zeroes as `%f` even if there aren't?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could check for existence of '.' in the string and either pad the value - e.g., t1+'.0' or use a more appropriate format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most brutal thing to do would be to check for dot in the format:

```py
t1_has_zeros = t1.find(".") > 0
```

And then parse accordingly. Pro tip - try to make sure that you have ISO-8601 formatted time - it will save you some headaches in parsing, so you could just call the native `datetime.fromisoformat`.